# Selecting all texts in a descendent as a single line using XPath and Python

Tags: python, html, xml, string, xpath

```
<div class="article">
      <h4 class="title"> 
        <a href="/some/linked/page.html">
          <i>Some text</i> followed by some more
        </a>
      </h4>
</div>
```

Hi! This is my first post, so kindly excuse me if I make any mistake regarding the posting etiquette. I have the above html code that I want to parse using XPath and Python. I want to create an XPath Query that would return me, "Some text followed by some more" as single string. There are more parts like this throughout the html document.

So far, I have tried this:

```
tree.xpath('//div[@class="article"]/h4[@class="title"]/descendant::text()[normalize-space()')
```

I had to use `normalize-space` because the original page has a lot of newlines and excess spaces in them, even blank lines. I could use `child`, but then I just get "followed by some more". I tried searching at other solutions, which suggested `string-join`, but it gives me either unregistered function and Invalid expression error.

Could someone please help me with constructing the query?

Comment: `normalize-space(//div[@class="article"]/h4[@class="title"]/a)`

Comment: It just selects the first div block.

Answer (score 0):

if all you want is to select all text nodes that are not whitespace nodes, then the following would do the trick:

```
.//text()[normalize-space(.) ne '']
```

alternatively, you can use selectors that will only select text() nodes that are children of elements that are supposed to contain text. but maybe the above is good enough for what you want to achieve.

Comment: Just tried running it, python says invalid predicate.

Comment: Three things: 1) The `ne` belongs to Xpath 2.0 +, in XPath 1.0 one can use the `not()` function or (with caution) the `!=` operator.  2) This expression returns a sequence of text nodes and there is no indication where the sequence of text node descendants for a particular `div` starts. 3) Most importantly, each text node is a node -- not a string as required in this question. And this string must be normalized.

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
normalize-space(.)
```

Here the assumption is that the `div` element is the context node.

**So, your specific solution may be:**

```
normalize-space((//div[@class='article'])[1])
```

**Proof, using XSLT**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    >>><xsl:value-of 
            select="normalize-space((//div[@class='article'])[1])"/>&lt;&lt;&lt;
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<div class="article">
      <h4 class="title"> 
        <a href="/some/linked/page.html">
          <i>Some text</i> followed by some more
        </a>
      </h4>
</div>
```

**The XPath expression is evaluated and the result is output**, delimited by suitable visual start/stop indicators:

```
>>>Some text followed by some more<<<
```

Comment: It works, but just selects the first div. I have multiple div too, of the same structure. Wanted something that selects all of them, not necessarily into the same line, but each div node should return it's own line saved into a list. The code is doing the required thing, but just for the first node.

Comment: @ParthaDas, This cannot be done with a single XPath 1.0 expression. If you can use XPath 2.0 and up (which it seems you cannot), then you can produce a sequence of all these strings with a single expression. If you are stuck with XPath 1.0, you can get all wanted `div` nodes with a single XPath 1.0 expression. Then you have to organize a loop using your host language (such as JavaScript, or C# or Java, or whatever you are using) and evaluate `normalize-space(.)` on each previously selected node.